# thrust::reduce_by_key performance with few key repetitions

Tags: c, cuda, thrust, reduction

I have to do keyed reductions of arrays with many different keys that repeat only once in a while:

```
keys =  {1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7, 8, 9, 9,10,11,...}
array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,...}

// after reduction
result = {1,2,7,5,6,7,17,10,23,13,14}
```

Using `thrust::reduce_by_key` (or any other segmented reduction method) is not the fastest option here as most operations are in fact just copies from one array to another.

What would be a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to know a priori which segments have length > 1 ? If the answer is no, then it seems like a hard problem because the cost of the data movement of just detecting the segments will be comparable to the cost of ```reduce_by_key```.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Yes, in fact I have the length of the segments stored in another array.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `reduce_by_key` *is* the appropriate algorithm to use here.  It's just that the current implementation in Thrust is not as fast as it could be.  To elaborate, there's nothing to prevent `reduce_by_key` from executing at memcpy speed, and I believe [other implementations](http://code.google.com/p/back40computing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/b40c/consecutive_reduction) already achieve that rate.  Our tentative plan for Thrust v1.7 includes making performance improvements to `reduce_by_key` and other scan-based algorithms using the codes in the related [back40computing](http://code.google.com/p/back40computing/) project.

Note that when the segments are either (1) long or of (2) uniform length then it's possible to do better than `reduce_by_key`.  For example, at some point it's more economical to use an offset-based segment descriptor than keys or head flags.  However, when the segments are short (as in your case) or of highly variable length, then an optimal `reduce_by_key` implementation is really the best tool for the job.